# ASP.Net custom dll works on Win 7 but not on Win Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, dll, windows-7, windows-server-2008, dllimport

I am developing a new project at work which uses an old dll file from an old project to encrypt passwords. You pass a string to a function and it returns an encrypted string back.

Now when I test it locally on my Win 7 machine it works OK, but when I put it on my Win Server 2008 it doesn't work. At first it gave an error for trying to work a 32-bit on a 64-bit, but I just set the "Enable 32-bit applications" to true in IIS app pool and it stoped give an error, but now when it gets to the row where it has to return the encrypted string it just sits there until it gives a timeout: "The connection was reset". But no yellow screen of death.

I used a program "dependency walker" to see what dll uses and from there I can see that I referes to kernerl32.dll which uses a kernerlBase.dll (this kernelBase.dll exists on my Win 7 machine but not on the Win Server). Just in case I tryed to return some static string from the dll like "error" after I rebuild the old project, but nothing returns. Still times out and as it seems it doesn't even go to the function I use to encrypt the string.

I use this...

```
[DllImport("MD5CriptUnix.dll")]
public static extern string md5_crypt(string pass, string salt);
```

...to import the dll and use it which again works on my machine and I think it works on the server because no errors are shown

Comment: Do you have access to the 2008 server to trace, view logs, step by step debug your app ? Is your 2008 server configured to provide detailled errors ? 
I know i'm off topic, but if your dll uses md5 hashing, as its name suggests it, it is obsolete. md5 is not a secure hashing solution anymore.

Comment: I do have access but didn't see anything strange in view logs exept maybe this when executing the dll..
Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e023cf, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18327, time stamp 0x4cb7341c, exception code 0xc0000374, fault offset 0x000abdcb, process id 0xfc4, application start time 0x01cda2e1fba3420a.
This ntdll.dll according to the "dependency walker" is used in  kernel32.dll along with kernelBase.dll 
About debug.. I'm not really sure how to debug this.

Comment: and I use md5 on purpose.. unfortunatly I don't have a choice..

Comment: I guess your problem lies here "0xc0000374" but I never had to debug such errors. Several times http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/ has been a very valuable source for me for debugging problems such as dll-loading and memory leaks. But each time, it took me a lot of time. I hope this will help (a little)